# How can I echo tags as plain text within a PHP loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to use a while loop to echo out an xml structure including the respective tags. In the example below, however, the  tag needs to be printed so the document can the be copied elsewhere:

```
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
echo "<name>".$row['name']."</name>";
}
?>
```

In this instance the while loop executes as expected but the opening and closing tags are not printed as plain text. I need to have them printed on screen so that I can copy the produced text elsewhere.

Comment: use php **htmlspecialchars()**

Comment: Please consider making use of functions built-in  php modules like I suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&lt;` for < and `&gt;` for >

Like this:

```
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
echo "&lt;name&gt;".$row['name']."&lt;/name&gt;";
}
?>
```

Or like this:

```
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
echo htmlspecialchars("<name>".$row['name']."</name>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider wrapping up your data in the built-in `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` functions of php modules.

```
<?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
        $var =  "<name>".$row['name']."</name>";
        $answer = htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($var));
        echo $answer ;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlentities for replace plain text to html entities.

```
<?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
         echo htmlentities("<name>".$row['name']."</name>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to remember all HTML entities, you can ask PHP to convert this for you automatically:

```
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
    echo htmlentities("<name>".$row['name']."</name>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand question:
use htmlspecialchars() function;

But you can copy it from page source (ctr+u in FF and Chrome) or execute php in OS shell and save result to file.

Answer (score -1):

By default, the browser will try to render the tags in your string, as a normal HTML. You should prevent this default action. You can do two things:

**One:** is to use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function, that will produce replace the characters used in HTML tags to their HTML entities.

```
<?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
        echo htmlentities("<name>".$row['name']."</name>");
    }
?>
```

**Two:** You can use `<pre> $str </pre>` tag, that assumes your text is already preformated, and browser will not change any of your characters.

```
<pre><?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
        echo "<name>".$row['name']."</name>";
    }
?></pre>
```